# remote execution via ssh doesn't follow links?

Tags: shell, ssh, wildcards

`ssh server ls /var/lib/edumate/backup/weekly/*DBB*` returns one file

```
/var/lib/edumate/backup/weekly/DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20120610020013.001
```

but `ssh server ls  /data/backup/weekly/*DBB*` returns what is in mounted linked directory

```
/data/backup/weekly/DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20120513020022.001
/data/backup/weekly/DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20120520020018.001
/data/backup/weekly/DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20120527020019.001
/data/backup/weekly/DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20120603020028.001
/data/backup/weekly/DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20120610020013.001
/data/backup/weekly/DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20120710120854.001
```

Where `/data` is on another partition

```
/dev/sdb2 on /data type ext3 (rw,acl,user_xattr)
```

and backup is a symlink to `/data/backup`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root       12 Jul 10 14:27 backup -> /data/backup/
```

Of course I am after the list of files from the mounted/linked directory. Is there any way **how I can use `/var/lib/edumate/backup` in `ls`** and not the linked one? Is `scp` going to behave the same?

Comment: On your client, from which you are executing the `ssh` command, change to your home directory and try again. I suspect a globbing issue.

Comment: hm, in fact I run it as php user through sudo from php script. But I tried from command line as php user too. I tried to changed to home dir of php user as you suggested and it worked. Now it works even from the php script (where I don't change to home dir. Any explanation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My best guess is that on your client machine, from which you ran `ssh`, that you also have a directory named `/var/lib/edumate/backup/weekly`. At the time you ran it, that directory on your client machine contained only the one file. But now it contains all the files you expect.

What happens is that the wildcard matching happens on the client machine rather than on the server. And at the time, there was probably only the one file there. Thus, what the server would have received from your command was:

```
ls /var/lib/edumate/backup/weekly/DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20120610020013.001
```

To prevent this in the future, run the command with quotes, such as:

```
ssh server ls "/var/lib/edumate/backup/weekly/*DBB*"
```

The wildcards will then be passed on to the server instead of being expanded by your shell on the client machine.

Comment: You're right that the same directory is on the client's system. But it's empty. One level up (still on a client's computer) is sitting a file that I was probably getting as a result from remote host. But know from whatever directory I do ssh the correct result is returned.

Comment: The file is no longer there, then. Or you mistyped it earlier and wound up with its actual location by mistake. In either case, putting the filename in quotes will prevent it from happening again.

Comment: I use the same command to be executed on the command line (I didn't type it - echoed from php and copied). And I didn't delete any file on the file system. So nothing you say applies.

Comment: In that case, you have gremlins in your system, and there's not much I can do beyond what I've already done. :)

Comment: This answer is actually correct, or mostly so. The fact is that your glob pattern `*DBB*` is expanded by your *local* shell, and whatever it's expanded to is passed to `ssh`. If you want it to be expanded by the remote shell it must be quoted.

Comment: OK, so how come it works correctly now even though it's not quoted? I am in the directory where one file exists with DBB string in its name and ssh returns correct result?

Comment: @Radek If there are matching files on the client, the shell expands the wildcards. If there are no matching files, the shell leaves the wildcards alone. Since you're specifying an absolute path, the current directory doesn't matter.